# Software Center keeps removing Office 2016

Tags: powershell, ms-office

On the Software Center management, Microsoft Office 2016 keeps being removed. 
Once removed, it goes into this stage where it's constantly trying to install (look at picture):

[image]

As a result, I searched up the following link http://www.potentengineer.com/task-sequence-stuck-installing-in-software-center/
that explains I have to run the following powershell script for the Software Center to complete the installation of Microsoft Office 2016 and stop removing the office 2016:

```
 # Fix for Software center show application stuck at Installing  
# https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e382da34-079c-4619-8fdb-e5e44c436857/software-center-show-application-stuck-at-installing?forum=configmanagerapps  
# Add service dependency for SMSTSMGR against CCMEXEC  
# Author: Mike Palmer  
# Date: 3rd July 2015  
# Version: 1.01 

# Get Service Details  
$service = get-service smstsmgr 

# Check ServiceDependedOn Array  
if (($service.ServicesDependedOn).name -notcontains "ccmexec")  
{  
 write-host "Not present...Configuring Service"  
 start-process sc.exe -ArgumentList "config smstsmgr depend= winmgmt/ccmexec" -wait  
}  
else  
{  
 write-host "Present..Taking no action"  
}
```

I am a super noob when it comes to powershell scripting. Please assist.
I tried running the powershell script but it does not solve the problem. Please assist. Thanks

Comment: any chance you have a machine with a mixture of 32 bit and 64 bit office components...office doesnt like that

Comment: You might ask tis question your administrator or in a SCCM forum.